# Reactive Forms | FormArray Runtime Control Issue | Angular 15

Tags: angular, forms, reactive, formarray

I am new to angular. I wrote one code to dynamically add controls and delete controls using delete button. It is working fine.
But at runtime I am able to input only one character in the controls that render in the browser initially and after pressing add button.
It is not showing any runtime/compile time error.

Can Anyone help me.

```
//html File Code


 <form [formGroup]="regform">
  <div formArrayName="details">
    <div
      *ngFor="let d of regform.controls.details.value; let i = index"
      [formGroupName]="i"
    >
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Full Name"
        formControlName="fullName"
      />
      &nbsp;

      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Roll Number"
        formControlName="rollNumber"
      />
      &nbsp;

      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Class Details"
        formControlName="class"
      />&nbsp;

      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Mobile Number"
        formControlName="mobileno"
      />&nbsp;

      <button
        style="
          background-color: #f44336;
          padding: 14px 20px;
          margin: 8px 0;
          border: none;
          cursor: pointer;
          opacity: 0.9;
        "
        (click)="deleteRow(i)"
      >
        X
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<br />

<div>
  <button
    style="
      background-color: #04aa6d;
      padding: 14px 20px;
      margin: 8px 0;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      opacity: 0.9;
    "
    (click)="addcontrol()"
  >
    Add
  </button>
</div>
```

// TS File Code is below

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-hwreactiveform',
  templateUrl: './hwreactiveform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hwreactiveform.component.css'],
})
export class HwreactiveformComponent {
  regform: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.regform = this._fb.group({
      details: this._fb.array([this.buildcontrol()]),
    });
  }

  buildcontrol() {
    return this._fb.group({
      fullName: [''],
      rollNumber: [''],
      class: [''],
      mobileno: [''],
    });
  }

  addcontrol() {
    const cont = <FormArray>this.regform.controls['details'];
    cont.push(this.buildcontrol());
  }

  deleteRow(index: any) {
    (<FormArray>this.regform.controls['details']).removeAt(index);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the stackblitz for you
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9dylb?file=src%2Fmain.ts

The problem is that you use a formControlValue for your *ngFor.

```
let d of regform.controls.details.value !!!
```

FormValue change when your input change value, as you type in your input (input event). Therefore your UI always re-render when it have any new input, that makes your forcus is out. Just make sure your UI just re-render when you click on button.

Comment: @MinhErratic, You should iterate over formArray.controls. NOTE: Always we use an auxiliar variable (in this case the array "details") strongly relationated with another object (in this case the FormArray) we need ask us if really it's neccesary

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate over the formArray.controls (it's unneccesary use the auxiliar array "details".

Just define a getter

```
get detailsFormArray()
{
    return this.regform.get('details') as FormArray
}

<div *ngFor="let d of detailsFormArray.controls; let i = index"
      [formGroupName]="i">
...
</div>
```

This allow simply

```
 addcontrol() {
    this.detailsFormArray.push(this.buildcontrol());
  }

  deleteRow(index: any) {
    this.detailsFormArray.removeAt(index);
  }
```

NOTE: keep simply, keep robust.